# Clang as C++ interpreter?

Tags: clang, llvm, interpreter

I'm intrigued by using Clang as embedded C++ interpreter. Is it possible to interpret "hello world" with it? The aim is to pass source filepath or source code as a string and get input/output streams **with no executables invocations** (it seems clang's `Driver` executes `clang` and/or linker executable).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider cling (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) which is C++ interpreter built in top of clang libraries.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. unfortunately i'm having strange cling errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082354/cling-error-incrementalexecutor-use-of-undefined-symbol